# It possible to pass variable from frontend to event when broadcasting public channel throuhg laravel echo server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo

I have worked code:

**Frontend code**
`resources/js/components/OnlineWall.vue`:

```
        mounted() {

            window.Echo.channel('laravel_database_new-payload')
                .listen('.new-payload-event', (e) => {
                    console.info('listen');
                    console.log(e.payload);
                })

        }
```

**Event code** `app/Events/NewPayload.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Payload;

class NewPayload implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $payload;

    /**
     * NewPayload constructor.
     * @param Payload $payload
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Payload $payload)
    {
        $this->payload = $payload;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('new-payload');
    }

    /**
     * Custom broadcast message name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'new-payload-event';
    }

}
```

If I fire event: `NewPayload::dispatch($testNewPayload);` all works fine.

But I need to pass integer variable from vue component to laravel event (city_id)

if city_id is identical to city_id of Payload model from event (in $testNewPayload), then fire event . Otherwise don't fire event.

It is possible?

Channel is public, Laravel 7.0

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
mounted() {

            window.Echo.channel(`laravel_database_new-payload.${this.city_id}`)
                .listen('.new-payload-event', (e) => {
                    console.info('listen');
                    console.log(e.payload);
                })

        }
```

```php
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('new-payload.'.$this->payload->city_id);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, this attempt only separate into different Channel, do you have solutions if we wanna capture other info from joining same public channel? Such as user's cookie